# IOS Location updates on background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, app-store, batterylevel

I need to know if i can get the location on background mode. Could i get the battery level to work with it.
Or the apple store will reject the app because the limits of the background modes I can work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run iOS Core Location in background forever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856827/how-to-run-ios-core-location-in-background-forever)

Answer (score 1):

Click on projects.
Click on Target.
Click on Capabilities.
Click on Background Modes.
Click on Location updates.

your location delegates are called even when your app is in background mode.

Apple docs have good information about saving battery. Which location services you need to use according to your apps need. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

To get battery level
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location in background mode.
And you can get battery level in background when location update is received.
But please take a look into [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

> 2.16 Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion,
>   local notifications, etc.